# c# fast sort and retrieve for small amount of key value pairs

Tags: c#, quicksort

I have a reoccuring operation which composed of build somekind of key/value pairs.
the key is type of Double.
I have from 1 up to 9 pairs eachtime.
and then I need to retrieve the values by the order of the keys.

So my question is what would be the best way to implement this set of pairs to achieve the best performance for te all operation?

thanks in advance

Comment: did u try anything? u can figure it out if u try some.

Comment: With such a small amount of data, it really doesn't matter how you implement it. Just use a built-in container with the default `Sort` method and call it a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother about the sorting algorithm, the .Net Framework already has efficient ones built in for 99.9999%<sup>*</sup> of feasible cases.

[`SortedList<double, T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) is likely your best bet, unless you have duplicate "keys" then just use a `List<Tuple<double,T>>` and call `Sort` or use `OrderBy` when you want the results.

10 items or less is nothing at all unless you're doing hundreds of millions of these sort operations at a time.

<sub>* relative hyperbole.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

You can use a SortedList or SortedDictionary.

But using a `double` as the key seems dangerous due to rounding issues.
See if you can use a `decimal` instead, it is much more reliable int he `Equals()` department.

Comment: +1, some odd edge cases with double could cause problem with keyed data structures.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. will be applied along with SortedList<double, T> as suggested above

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe

```
var sorted = from k in yourContainer.Keys
             orderby yourContainer[k] ascending
             select k;
```

Answer (score 0):

`double` is not a good candidate as a `key`.

But if you want to use it by the way, can use just a `Dictionary<double, ..something..>` or

```
SortedList<double, ..something..>
```